# SSRS ReportViewer 401 (Machine Account) domain\machine$

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, reportviewer

Before I go into the issue let me first explain the architecture I'm working with.

- DB-Server - SQL Server 2019, Windows 2019
- SSRS-Server - SSRS 2019, Windows 2019
- Web-Server - IIS v10, Windows 2019

All servers are on the same domain.

The application rendering the report is written in ASP.NET using the rsweb:ReportViewer control.

**Requirement:** I need the ability to access reports from the ASP.NET application using a machine level account.

**Current Error:** ***The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.***

**What I've done so far...**

- Added machine account to SSRS.  I've given it permissions at all levels: site settings, folders, reports.  Once I get it working I'll dumb down the rights but for now I need it working.  This machine level account is the Web-Server.  My assumption is any access from the Web-Server to the SSRS-Server will be granted.

[image]

- Changed the application pool's identity to LocalSystem.  Yes this may violate least privilege but again I'm viewing this as a POC at this point.  I've also tried NetworkService.

[image]

- Web.config.  There may be something I need to do here to make this work.  I've tried using identity impersonate but I had no success but it's possible I didn't use it in combination with another setting.  When I have the authentication mode set to Windows the Windows Identity used by ASP.NET is NT AUTHORITY\IUSR.  Removing this line gives me NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the Windows Identity.  I would think the NETWORK SERVICE account would be granted; however, this still results in a 401 error.

[image]

- Modified the "rsreportserver.config" file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config)

[image]

- ASP.NET ReportViewer setup:

  ```
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = rc.report_ssrs_path;
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(rc.report_ssrs_url);

   SqlConnectionStringBuilder conString = new Database().conBuilder;
   List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
   parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ConString", conString.ConnectionString));
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);

   DataSourceCredentials dsc = new DataSourceCredentials();
   dsc.Name = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetDataSources()[0].Name;
   dsc.UserId = conString.UserID;
   dsc.Password = conString.Password;
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] {
       dsc });

   ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
  ```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.  I've scoured the internet for a solution to this with no luck.  It seems like it should be possible and a lot of the things I've read make it sound like it is.  I'm sure I'm just missing something minor.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.